A "Transform" po-up keeps appearing whenever I left click
I'm kinda new to Blender, and everything was going fine until, for some unknown reason, a "Transform" pop-up just started appearing whenever I use left click.
The said pop-up:

It contains multiple check boxes like "Correct Face Attribut...", "Keep Connected" and a "Mirror" option with multiple check boxes X, Y and Z
Can someone explain to me what it is and also how to disable it, because I can't do anything with left click since it just opens the pop-up again?
I have tried restarting both Blender and my PC. The bug does not occur after reloading the default settings, but occurs again when reopening Blender.

Do you have the "selection" tool enabled (it's on the left side of the screen, and if it's not, press T)

That option should only appear when you click on the 'Options' dropdown at the top-right of the 3D view in Edit mode. I can't think of any reason why it might appear if you click anywhere else in the 3D view. Maybe try File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings and see if that cures the problem?

DanielMöller: Yes I have it enabled, but the bug was occuring with every other tool in the edit mode and also in the object mode (except Annotate for some reason)
But, like JohnEason suggested, I have reset to factory settings the sofware and it solved the problem. But it's worth saying that loading a workspace which was saved with the bug bring it back on any new file after that, but it when off again when I reseted to factory setting one again

Update, the bug occures whenever I load a workspace, even after deinstaling and reinstaling Blender

I'm having the same problem, Did you figure out what this is?

@MilesOgden Unfortunately, no. I have to reload the factory settings each time I open Blender before opening any file
